# Why can't save image to database in this way?

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, image-uploading

I want to save Image and some other information to databse in my asp.net mc3 project. I've saved Image to database before and it worked. my code in my controller was this:

```
public ActionResult savetodb()
{
    if (Request.Files.Count > 0 && Request.Files[0] != null)
        {
             HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];
             var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Image"), file.FileName); 
             file.SaveAs(path);
             byte[] buffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
             myAd.AdImage = buffer;
             StoreDb.AddToAds(myAd);
             StoreDb.SaveChanges();
        }
        return View();      
    }
}
```

Now I changed the table and want to save other information more than Image to database. Now my code is like this:

```
 public ActionResult savetodb(AdvertiseView model)
 {
     if (Request.Files.Count > 0 && Request.Files[0] != null)
     {
         HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];
         var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Image"), file.FileName);
         file.SaveAs(path);
         byte[] buffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
         myAd.AdImage = buffer;
     }
     myAd.AdTitle = model.AdTitle;
     myAd.AdContext = model.context;
     myAd.AdScope = model.Scope;
     storedb.AddToAds(myAd);
     storedb.SaveChanges();
     return View();
}
```

there isn't any problem with other infos but image cant be saved. I understand that

```
Request.Files.Count
```

return 0. I don't know what should I do now. Can anybody help me please? Thanks alot.

Comment: Did you set enctype on HTML form? `<form enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: Can you include a snippet of your view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use a view model.

Let's suppose that you have a domain model first:

```
public class MyDomainModel
{
    public byte[] AdImage { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

then define a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // TODO: move this mapping logic into a 
        // mapping layer to avoid polluting the controller
        // I would recommend AutoMapper for this purpose
        // http://automapper.org/
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            model.File.InputStream.CopyTo(stream);
            var image = stream.ToArray();
            var domainModel = new MyDomainModel
            {
                AdImage = image,
                Description = model.Description
            };

            // TODO: persist the domain model by passing it to a method
            // on your DAL layer
        }

        return Content("Thanks for submitting");
    }
}
```

and once the recommended refactoring is complete:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        MyDomainModel domainModel = Mapper.Map<MyViewModel, MyDomainModel>(model);

        // TODO: persist the domain model by passing it to a method
        // on your DAL layer

        return Content("Thanks for submitting");
    }
}
```

and finally a view to allow the user upload the file:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Description)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Description)
    </div>

    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.File)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.File, new { type = "file" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.File)
    </div>    
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `HttpPostedFileBase` as a parameter on the action.

Use this if you are sending only one file. If you are allowing multiple then you have to use `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files` as the param.

```
public ActionResult savetodb(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if(file != null)
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Image"), file.FileName);
        file.SaveAs(path);
        byte[] buffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        myAd.AdImage = buffer;
        StoreDb.AddToAds(myAd);
        StoreDb.SaveChanges();
    }
    return View();      
}
```

You must also make sure your Form is properly built in your View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {
....
}
```

Also be aware that by default, the browser filesize upload limit is 4MB, if you want to upload anything larger than that you will need to configure your settings in the web.config file

Comment: I would also recommend not to store the file physically on the server, and within the site itself. Just store it on the DB directly.
That leaves your site clean of any uploads plus it also is compatible with deployment in a farm environment.

Comment: I think that is an IT technical problem, not necessarily a development problem. If the image count and size is large then in the DB is not a good solution unless the IT dept has a nice killer fast cluster with fast SANs

Comment: @AlfalfaStrange: Thanks for your answer and good advise. I try this code but I don't know why doesn't work. It looks correct. In my database the Image value is NULL.

Comment: @Tena Well you are first saving the image to the file system, is it physically there before trying to save to DB?

Comment: @AlfalfaStrange: No it isn't. I checked, In this code the value of file in NULL. When I want to save just Image (with a table that has just one column for Image) it works, but when I want to use other information like the code I described above, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Tena Try Darin's solution, he's the defacto goto Guru here :-) if the file isn't making it to the filesystem then that's a problem. Again, make sure you aren't trying to upload something larger than 4MB

Comment: @AlfalfaStrange OK and Thanks for your good advise. You helped me before and Thanks again.

Comment: @Tena You're welcome, glad I could help in what little bit I can! Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Add a property to your view model to get this file:

```
public class AdvertiseView
{
    ...    
    public HttpPostedFileBase NameOfFileInput;
    ....
}
```

So you can grab the file as a property of the model:

```
if (myAd.NameOfFileInput != null)
{
    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Image"), myAd.NameOfFileInput.FileName);
    myAd.NameOfFileInput.SaveAs(path);
    byte[] buffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    myAd.AdImage = buffer;
}
```

Of course you can use the same property `AdImage` and just save it to the right place, without copying the buffer if its of the same type.